# Using AWS Lambda with Cognito and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

How to get user in Lambda function? User is authenticated in Cognito and invokes lambda with API Gateway. API Gateway method has AWS_IAM authorizer and checked "Use Lambda Proxy integration" checkbox

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked AWS_IAM API Gateway, identity of the end user available to your function. You can access the Identity ID as follows.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var identity = event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId;
    console.log("clientID = " + identity);

    context.succeed("Your client ID is " + identity);
}
```

Then using the [AWS SDK for Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#describeIdentity-property) invoking `describeIdentity-property` method, you should be able to retrieve additional information available for the identity.

```
var params = {
  IdentityId: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
cognitoidentity.describeIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: There is no context.identity property. I call API using https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-api-gateway-client

context object has properties: callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop, logGroupName, logStreamName, functionName, memoryLimitInMB, functionVersion, invokeid, awsRequestId, invokedFunctionArn

Comment: But there is event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId in event object. Thank you

Comment: I checked the mobile SDK invocations. But thanks will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Do you know how to get user attributes? I get Logins array in describeIdentity. Users are in User Pool and they have attributes

Comment: Did you try invoking describeIdentity-property method? in NodeSDK for Cognito

Comment: Do you mean DescribeIdentityProvider?