# How to get current user username in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I use AWS Lambda + Cognito (User Pool + Federated Identity) + API Gateway. Users authenticate in WEB application with [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js) and invokes API with [aws-api-gateway-client](https://github.com/kndt84/aws-api-gateway-client). API Gateway methods have AWS_IAM authorizer. How to get username (from User Pool) in Lambda function?

Comment: How is this a different question from your previous post(s)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120881/how-to-get-cognito-user-in-aws-lambda
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108431/using-aws-lambda-with-cognito-and-api-gateway

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963906/how-to-get-user-attributes-username-email-etc-using-cognito-identity-id

Comment: @MarkB I've removed that post

Answer (score 3):

You can use `event.identity.username`

```
exports.handler = async (event, _, callback) => {
   try {
        console.log('event', event);
        console.log('event.identity.username', event.identity.username);
        const userId = event.identity.username;
        console.log('userId', userId);

        callback(null, true);
   } catch(e) {
       console.log(e);
       callback(e);
   }
};
```

Comment: event.identity dosent have a field named username. Am I missing something?

Comment: @VikasSaini hmm, maybe because of you not use cognito?

Comment: Ok let me share more details, apologies for delay in comment response.
I use Cognito User Pool + Identity Pool, my lambda is in VPC behind API gateway secured via IAM Authorizer. After passing APIG, my lambda receives the event that contains event.requestContext.identity , now this object dosent have much information, only cognitoIdentityPoolId, cognitoAuthenticationType, cognitoAuthenticationProvider. Ofcourse I can get sub Id from this but I wanted email, name, groups etc. For this I had to do another call to cognito which takes another 500ms

Comment: @VikasSaini I guess if you use IAM Authorizer it would not work, try to change type

Answer (score 2):

Modify the request sent to your Lambda function using `aws-api-gateway-client` to pass the JWT `ID Token` in the request header. 
You may need to [ensure your API gateway is configured to forward headers](https://kennbrodhagen.net/2015/12/06/how-to-create-a-request-object-for-your-lambda-event-from-api-gateway/).

```
apigClient.invokeApi(
  params,
  pathTemplate, 
  method,
  { { headers: { IDToken } } }, 
  body);
```

> The ID Token should be used here as its payload contains *cognito:username* field

The `ID Token` is gotten after authentication using `amazon-cognito-identity-js`.

You can parse this field from the header of the request in your lambda handler function.

[Verify its signature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html) before trusting the contents of its payload.

```
import { util } from 'aws-sdk/global';

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  // Parse ID Token from request header
  const headers = event.headers;
  const idToken = headers.IDToken;

  ...
};
```

Comment: You cannot securely encrypt a token on the client side and expect it to be untouched on the server side. Retrieving details from a JWT token without checking the signature is very unsafe.

Comment: You make a good point about not trusting the JWT token. My answer can be updated to forward the IDToken since that contains the Cognito username.

Answer (score 0):

event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.username

Thats where I get it from other places it gives null